# Magento2.1 - How to make a discout coupon with free shipping included?

Tags: magento2, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

Did someone find out how to give discount AND free shipping with a coupon code?
I couldn't create such a price cart rule. It always was either discount or free shipping.

Answer (score 1):

there is already a described issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6294
It will be fixed in the next Magento Version 2.1.3
When you need it now, look at this commit: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d66748032936d4f48c937343a9906fea8acdd132

I've run into this issue and fixed it with mentioned above patch.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to create discount coupon with free shipping

Market > Cart Price Rules > Add New Rules

Step 1 : Rule Information

Fill all required field according to your need and select specific coupon for coupon generation.

Step 2: Conditions

make conditions according to your need.

Step 3: Actions

select discount amount and discount percentage whatever you want in apply filed.

Enter discount amount in "Discount amount filed"

Select free shipping filed "For matching items only"

enter condition according to need

Step 4 : Labels

Step 5 : Manage Coupon Codes

Enter coupon Qty, Codelength, Code format

After filling these field click on generate button.